# How to get variable and calling on props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

So i want the value in the user view table to increase according to what has been input. Like this image:

[image]

However I can't or don't know how to call the value into the user props.

And here's the code:

**AddUserForm.js**

[Full Code](https://github.com/mafalaz/pic-note/commit/3d197a7093a7a24fc76c145b873565ed31fb75d7)

```
const handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target

    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })

    sum = value.toString()
    .split('+')
    .map(value => Number(value))
    .reduce((agg, value) => agg + value, 0);
    console.log(sum)
}
```

**UserTable.js**

[Full Code](https://github.com/mafalaz/pic-note/commit/5cb25356007d3d1ac3e72e87d3a5bad73fbe56d6)

```
<tbody>
  {props.users.length > 0 ? (
    props.users.map(user => (
      <tr key={user.id}>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.cabang}</td>
        <td>{user.dealer * 40}</td>
        <td>{user.cod * 60}</td>
        <td>{user.jtr * 65}</td>
        <td>{user.gosend * 75}</td>
        <td>{user.reguler * 200}</td>
        <td>{user.total = parseInt(user.cabang * 25) + parseInt(user.dealer * 40) + parseInt(user.cod * 60) + parseInt(user.jtr * 65) + parseInt(user.gosend * 75) + parseInt(user.reguler * 200)}</td>
        <td>
```

I'm sorry if this question has already been discussed. Before making this question, I've searched and can't find it according to my case.

and I've tried various ways but still not working.

Thank you in advance :)